# why in this code end loop is not get end?

Tags: c++, stl

I am tring to pop the data in the vector. But after printing code is not coming out
Why? What should be done to make it correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef struct add
{
        string name;
        string address;
}Address;
typedef struct st
{
        vector<Address>madder;
}SLL;

int main()
{
        SLL * st;
        int n=3;
        Address ad,rad;
        while(n--)
        {
                cout << "enter the name : ";
                cin >> ad.name;
                cout << "enter the adderess : ";
                cin >> ad.address;
                st->madder.push_back(ad);
        }
        while (!st->madder.empty())
        {
                rad = st->madder.back();
                cout << rad.name << " " <<rad.address <<endl;
                st->madder.pop_back();
        }

}
```

Comment: Where was `st` allocated? Why is it a pointer?

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. Elevate warning level if you aren't getting any.

Comment: `typedef struct` in `c++` you don't need the `typedef` before `struct`

Comment: Adding as an improvement suggestion: You should use `getline(cin, ad.name);` and `getline(cin, ad.address);` instead of `cin >> ad.name;` and `cin >> ad.address;` as in most of real world examples, name and address of a person contain space(s) in them. `cin >> string` will stop reading as soon as it encounters a white-space character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must allocate an object to be pointed at by `st` before dereferencing `st`.

Also you should delete what is allocated.

```
int main()
{
        SLL * st;
        int n=3;
        Address ad,rad;
        st = new SLL; // add this
        while(n--)
        {
                cout << "enter the name : ";
                cin >> ad.name;
                cout << "enter the adderess : ";
                cin >> ad.address;
                st->madder.push_back(ad);
        }
        while (!st->madder.empty())
        {
                rad = st->madder.back();
                cout << rad.name << " " <<rad.address <<endl;
                st->madder.pop_back();
        }
        delete st; // add this

}
```

Another option is not using the pointer and allocating the `SLL` object directly as variable.

```
int main()
{
        SLL st;
        int n=3;
        Address ad,rad;
        while(n--)
        {
                cout << "enter the name : ";
                cin >> ad.name;
                cout << "enter the adderess : ";
                cin >> ad.address;
                st.madder.push_back(ad);
        }
        while (!st.madder.empty())
        {
                rad = st.madder.back();
                cout << rad.name << " " <<rad.address <<endl;
                st.madder.pop_back();
        }

}
```

Comment: If you're fixing his code, I'd put st on the stack as there's no need for it to be dynamically allocated.